# Knapp, Lie Groups: Beyond an Introduction, Corollary II.2.38

Tags: proof-explanation, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am studying root systems using Knapp's book, *Lie Groups: beyond an Introduction*. I am not able to understand the logic of a minor point in his proof of Corollary 2.38, which states:

[image]

In his proof, he first showed that,

> $\beta(H_{\alpha})$ is rational for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\Delta$,

where $H_{\alpha}$ is an element in a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of a complex semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ satisfying $\alpha(H) = B(H, H_\alpha)$, $\Delta$ denotes the set of all roots, and $B$ is the Killing form.

He then constructed a real vector space $V = \bigoplus_{j=1}^l \mathbb{R} \omega_j$ of all members of $\mathfrak{h}^*$ that are real on all of $H_{\alpha_1}, \cdots, H_{\alpha_l}$, where $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} \mathfrak{h} = l$ and $H_{\alpha_1}, \cdots, H_{\alpha_l}$ is a basis of $\mathfrak{h}$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Up till now I can understand everything, but then he claimed that because $\beta(H_{\alpha})$ is rational for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$, all roots are in $V$. **This is the part I don't understand. Why do we need to prove that $\beta(H_{\alpha})$ is rational if the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$ and each basis can be multiplied by $\mathbb{R}$ to become irrational?**

For your reference, here's a screenshot of the whole proof of the corollary.
[image]

Comment: I assume the point here is that rational implies real, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$. So because the roots are rational and thus real on the coroots they live in $V$.

Comment: I see. Thanks again!